# SourceTree doesn't show remote tags

Tags: git, tags, atlassian-sourcetree

I've created a tag through Bitbucket website --> placed it by mistake on a commit in Develop branch not the master
[image]

I wish to delete the tag.
Connecting to my repository through SourceTree with Develop branch checkout.
The tag isn't showing when clicking 'tag' on the left panel nor when clicking in 'tag' button in the menu and the tag modal window opens with no tags to remove

[image]

Please advise (I haven't installed git on my computer to access through command line)

Comment: Git itself does not *have* "remote tags": you either have a tag (which is local), or you don't have that tag. The fact that some *other* Git may have some tag is not interesting to Git, except when you connect your (local) Git *to* that other Git and say "fetch me stuff including tags": *then* your Git looks at their tags. But SourceTree is not Git, it's some sort of user interface, so it's certainly possible that SourceTree *should* check the tags over yonder, on bitbucket, here. I don't use SourceTree so I can't say much about that.

Comment: In any case, it seems like you should be able to delete the tag through the Bitbucket web interface, the same way you created it. That would fix the problem regardless of what SourceTree ought to do.

Comment: @torek have you deleted  tags through bitbucket website? If so please elaborate how - I didn't find a way to do it, and didn't find tutorials/answers for that

Comment: No, my repositories are all on GitHub. If you can create a tag, but not delete one, that seems like a defective hosting system, though.

Comment: SourceTree also doesn't get remote tags while fetch/pull. You should use some other git client for pull and then SourceTree to browse. This is so stupid.

Answer (score 21):

To fetch "remote tags" with SourceTree:

1. click the "Fetch" button,
2. check the "Fetch all tags" checkbox,
3. press "OK".

Then you should see that tag in the "Remove Tag" dialog.

Unfortunately this behavior cannot be enabled by default.  It has been requested as an enhancement more than 5 years ago (!) but it is not yet available.  See [SRCTREEWIN-6618](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-6618) (you can vote for it).

Comment: The "Fetch all tags" checkbox did the trick for me. Easy to miss.